# How could I make FFTW Hilbert transform calculate faster?

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fftw

I'm using the Hilbert transform function from the FFTW source.
Because I am going to use it in my DAQ with data streaming mode.
The function is working fine but the calculation speed is slow which will cause the FIFO overflow.
I've heard that move the `fftw_plan()` outside from the `hilbert()` for reuse the `plan` might be useful, however, it's an error once I did that, saying `Exception thrown at 0x0000000070769240 (libfftw3-3.dll) in CppFFTW.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.` at the `fftw_destroy_plan(plan);`. Does anyone has similar experiences or even better solution to boost up the `hilbert()` calculation?

Here is what I've tried (2020 12/26 edited):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

//macros for real and imaginary parts
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1
//length of complex array
#define N 8

fftw_complex* out;
fftw_plan plan;


void hilbert(const double* in, fftw_complex* out)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    //fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    //fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    int hN = N >> 1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    //plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // do some cleaning
    //fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    //fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }



   




}
/* Displays complex numbers in the form a +/- bi. */
void displayComplex(fftw_complex* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (y[i][IMAG] < 0)
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "-" << abs(y[i][IMAG]) << "i" << endl;
        else
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "+" << y[i][IMAG] << "i" << endl;
    }
}



/* Test */
int main()
{
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    

    
    // input array
    double x[N];
    // output array
    fftw_complex y[N];
    // fill the first of some numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        x[i] = i + 1;  // i.e.{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}
    }
    //clock_t begin = clock();
    // compute the FFT of x and store the result in y.
    hilbert(x, y);
    // display the result
    cout << "Hilbert =" << endl;
    displayComplex(y);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
}
```

Here is the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>


using namespace std;

//macros for real and imaginary parts
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1
//length of complex array
#define N 8

void hilbert(const double* in, fftw_complex* out)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    int hN = N >> 1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // do some cleaning
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }



   




}
/* Displays complex numbers in the form a +/- bi. */
void displayComplex(fftw_complex* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (y[i][IMAG] < 0)
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "-" << abs(y[i][IMAG]) << "i" << endl;
        else
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "+" << y[i][IMAG] << "i" << endl;
    }
}



/* Test */
int main()
{
    
 
    // input array
    double x[N];
    // output array
    fftw_complex y[N];
    // fill the first of some numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        x[i] = i + 1;  // i.e.{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}
    }
    // compute the FFT of x and store the result in y.
    hilbert(x, y);
    // display the result
    cout << "Hilbert =" << endl;
    displayComplex(y);
 
}
```

The exact output

```
Hilbert =
1+3.82843i
2-1i
3-1i
4-1.82843i
5-1.82843i
6-1i
7-1i
8+3.82843i
```

Comment: Maybe you could make this question answerable, by re-focusing the question on this part in your statement: "however, it's buggy once I did that. ". 

The docs to FFTW say exactly to re-use the fftw_plan. So, what have you tried and what is the "buggy" effect that you see?

Comment: Edited, the reason why I said that is because I'm not sure if my method is right.

Comment: Why override a clean struct? Instead of `out[i][REAL]`, do: `out[i].re`. I'm not even sure that they are equivalent [yours _might_ be UB] and the `.re` is how the struct is defined and what the lib expects. Likewise for `out[i].im`

Comment: Is it helpful for changing a few alphabet...?

Comment: `out` is a _pointer_, so accessing it via `out[i][anything]` is _wrong_. I'm surprised it compiled because there is no way to tell the compiler about the row count. It _is_ UB and you're accessing _beyond_ the end of the array. When you do: `out[i][1]` you are _not_ setting the `.im` part of `out[i]`. You are trashing `out[i + 1]`. Eventually, that causes you to scibble past the end of your [stack] array--that is UB [undefined behavior].

Comment: Okay ... The `.re` is for an older version of the lib. I (re)installed the correct version here. I've built your _original_ code cleanly as is. I've run it. It ran to completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For speed, you definitely want to reuse FFTW plans if possible. When reusing a plan across multiple calls to hilbert, remove the `fftw_destroy_plan(plan)` line within hilbert, otherwise the plan won't be valid to use in the next call. Instead, destroy the plan at the end of the program.

Edit: I had missed previously that you use two plans, one for forward transformation, another for backward. In `hilbert()`, remove all calls to `fftw_plan_dft_1d`,  `fftw_destroy_plan`, and `fftw_cleanup`; the only FFTW call should be `fftw_execute`. Instead, create both plans up front once at the beginning of the program, and destroy them at the end of the program.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean I have to delete the 2 lines `fftw_destroy_plan(plan)` ?

Comment: Oops, I missed earlier that you use two FFTW plans. You are right, both destroy lines should be removed. Please see the edit on my post.

Comment: Do you mean `plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` too ? For better understanding, could you give me an edited script to show which part need to remove and which part need to move to outside of the `hilbert()` and which part still need to be leave in the function? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please take a look to my post, I tried how you said, but a similar error still occurred, could you point out where I did wrong? thanks!

Comment: Looking at your updated code, plan creation and destroy commands are no longer in `hilbert`; that's good. What's missing is now those plans need to be created at the beginning or `main`. Of course, attempting to execute a plan without initializing it won't work. To create the plans, declare two `fftw_plan` variables as globals (two plans: one for forward, another for backwards) and use `fftw_plan_dft_1d` to initialize each of them. Then at the end of `main`, call `fftw_destroy_plan` on each of them to clean up.

Comment: Do you mean I need add these two code `fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` and `plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` to the `main`? But once I did that I have to declare the two `out` variable of ``fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` What type is appropriate?

Comment: Updated the newest modification, please take a look. There is still a error happened in `int hN = N >> 1; // half of the length (N/2)`, saying a similar event `Exception thrown at 0x0000000070769240 (libfftw3-3.dll) in CppFFTW.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.` Hope I can solve this whole problem as my Christmas gift.

Answer (score 1):

After several tried, here is the successful FFTW `hilbert()` improvement.
Moved out the two `fftw_plan` and let them initialized in the `main()`, plus, the `fftw_destroy_plan` were moved too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

//macros for real and imaginary parts
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1
//length of complex array
#define N 8
fftw_complex y[N];



void hilbert(const double* in, fftw_complex* out, fftw_plan plan_forward, fftw_plan plan_backward)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    //fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan_forward);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    //fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
    int hN = N >> 1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    //plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan_backward);
    // do some cleaning
    //fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward);
    //fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }








}
/* Displays complex numbers in the form a +/- bi. */
void displayComplex(fftw_complex* y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (y[i][IMAG] < 0)
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "-" << abs(y[i][IMAG]) << "i" << endl;
        else
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "+" << y[i][IMAG] << "i" << endl;
    }
}



/* Test */
int main()
{
    // input array
    double x[N];
    // output array
    //fftw_complex y[N];
    fftw_plan plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, y, y, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, y, y, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    



   
    // fill the first of some numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        x[i] = i + 1;  // i.e.{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}
    }
    // compute the FFT of x and store the result in y.
    hilbert(x, y, plan_forward, plan_backward);
    
    // display the result
    cout << "Hilbert =" << endl;
    
    displayComplex(y);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward);
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefaced by my top comments ...

Okay ... After a few false starts ...

Your second version had some issues.

Notably, you were *not* allocating `out`.

Also, to be safe, I believe that you need *two* `fftw_plan` structs, one for forward and one for backward.

These should be allocated/initialized *once* in `main`.

And, remove any allocation/destruction calls in `hilbert`. That way, it can be called multiple times by just changing the data placed in `out`.

The cleanup code can go to the bottom of `main`.

I've created a cleaned up and working version of your second version. I've shown the difference of old vs new code with `cpp` conditionals:

```
#if 0
// old code ...
#else
// new code ...
#endif
```

So, here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

//macros for real and imaginary parts
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1

//length of complex array
#define N 8

fftw_plan plan_fwd;
fftw_plan plan_bwd;
fftw_complex *out;

void
hilbert(const double *in, fftw_complex *out)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }

    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    // fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE); // This line has been moved to the main function

    fftw_execute(plan_fwd);

    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
#if 0
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_fwd);
#endif
    int hN = N >> 1;                    // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN;                    // the number of remaining elements

    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    // (those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }

    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }

    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
#if 0
    plan_bwd = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
#endif
    fftw_execute(plan_bwd);
    // do some cleaning
#if 0
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_bwd);
    fftw_cleanup();
#endif

    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }
}

/* Displays complex numbers in the form a +/- bi. */
void
displayComplex(fftw_complex * y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (y[i][IMAG] < 0)
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "-" << abs(y[i][IMAG]) << "i" << endl;
        else
            cout << y[i][REAL] << "+" << y[i][IMAG] << "i" << endl;
    }
}

/* Test */
int
main()
{

#if 1
    out = (fftw_complex *) malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
#endif

    plan_fwd = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    plan_bwd = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    // input array
    double x[N];

    // output array
    fftw_complex y[N];

    // fill the first of some numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        x[i] = i + 1;                   // i.e.{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}
    }
    clock_t begin = clock();

    // compute the FFT of x and store the result in y.
    hilbert(x, y);
    // display the result
    cout << "Hilbert =" << endl;
    displayComplex(y);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("%f", time_spent);

    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_fwd);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_bwd);
    fftw_cleanup();
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
Hilbert =
0.125+0i
0.5+0i
0.75+0i
1+0i
0.625+0i
0+0i
0+0i
0+0i
0.000171
```

Comment: Thanks Craig but the output answer wasn’t right

Comment: Sorry for the late review, I think what you presented was almost fit to the concept, however, the output answer was wrong. But I think we can keep improving base on your code. Btw, I am not the guy who gave the downvote ;)

Comment: I updated the actual output value in the question part, please take a look. Thanks!